# How to get the previous state in React functional component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am writing a React component using hooks and I try to get the previous state of some variable, i.e, render the current and previous count in the Counter: [CodeSandBox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-kilby-4jxni?file=/src/App.js)

```
function usePrevious(value) {
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  }, [value]); 

  return ref.current;
}

const Counter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  const prevCount = usePrevious(count)
  
  const [x,setX] = useState(0)
  
  return (
    <div>
      <p>count: {count}, prev count: {prevCount}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Add count
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => setX(x + 1)}>
        Change x
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

When I click "Add count", everything is ok.
But if I click the "Change X" button, which triggers a re-render of the component, then I will get the current value of count but not the value before changing.

So how can I get the correct previous count even if there is a re-render?

Comment: save the value of `count` in a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) before calling the `setCount`

Comment: But thats why you using this usePrevious hook... To get the previous value, why u asking how to get the previous value then?

Comment: @Yousaf Thanks. Is there any approach to use a custom hook to do this?

Comment: Yes; inside the custom hook, save the value in a ref and the hook should return a function that updates the value saved in a ref. Then inside the component, call the function from the custom hook to save the current value of `count` and then call `setCount`.

Comment: @DennisVash I use the usePrevious hook just because I saw the FAQ mentioned here: [How to get the previous props or state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#can-i-run-an-effect-only-on-updates)

Answer (score 0):

Why just store the previous count in another State or object

```
        const Counter = () => {
            const [count, setCount] = useState({
            current: 0,
            previous: 0
            })
            const prevCount = usePrevious(count)
            
            const [x,setX] = useState(0)
            
            return (
            <div>
                <p>count: {count.current}, prev count: {count.prev}</p>
                <button onClick={() => setCount((prev) => {prev.current: prev.current + 1, prev.previous: prev.current  })}>
                Add count
                </button>
                <button onClick={() => setX(x + 1)}>
                Change x
                </button>
            </div>
            )
        }
```